# Can one say " the" form of a reasoning? ( About the " valid form" approach to validity).

Tags: logic, soft-question

Sometimes one reads things such as : a reasoning is valid iff the form of this reasoning is a valid form.

References : Klenk, Understanding logic

This leads to thinking that the fact each reasoning has a form, a " unique" form is crucial.

However, in Peter Smith's introduction to logic, I read that one cannot properly talk about " the" form of a reasoning; every reasoning instantiates many forms.

In that case, is the idea of " valid forms of reasoning" useless?

Is the " valid form" approach to validity correct?

Comment: See [Logical Form](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-form/) : we say also "formal logic".

Comment: I voted to close as "not about mathematics". I think you would get better answers on philosophy stackexchange.

Comment: Logic is this last part of philosophy that still belongs to science, and more precisely, to mathematics. To be discussed ( this time, on PSE, I agree). Any question regarding validity belongs to (meta)logic ( that's fact, no?).

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames I did not mean to suggest that logic is not a part of mathematics. My research is in mathematical logic, and what I do is definitely mathematics! While I may have misinterpreted it, your question seems to me to be about philosophical logic, or the philosophy of logic, and I don't think that you're going to get an answer you're satisfied with from mathematicians.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames That is, to make this a well-formed mathematical question, one needs to make precise definitions of a "reasoning", a "form", and a "valid form". These are not terms that are commonly used in *mathematical* logic - in my experience, in mathematical logic, there is no meaningful distinction between a proof and the form of the proof - a proof only makes sense in the context of some logical system, and it is formed according to precise structural rules. Maybe you have definitions of "reasoning", "form", and "valid form" in mind. If so, you should include them in the question.

Comment: On the other hand, the way I interpreted the question is that "reasoning" is an informal term, describing the kinds of logical reasoning actually done by people. And the question is about trying to understand the *nature* of reasoning by asking whether every reasoning can be formalized in a unique way. If that's what you meant, then this is squarely a question about philosophy.